# Quartz 2D: CGColorSpaceCreateLab: Purpose of range parameter?

Tags: colors, core-graphics

In Quartz 2D, the [`CGColorSpaceCreateLab()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1408879-cgcolorspacecreatelab/) function takes a `range` parameter defined as follows:

> **CGFloat range[4]:** An array of 4 numbers that specify the range of valid values for the a* and b* components of the color space. The a* component represents values running from green to red, and the b* component represents values running from blue to yellow.

The question is, what does this parameter actually *do*?

I can think of at least three possible scenarios.

**Option 1: Maybe it scales the component values**

Say I have two color spaces with different ranges:

```
CGFloat range1[] = {  -10,  10,  -10,  10 };
CGFloat range2[] = { -100, 100, -100, 100 };
CGColorSpaceRef space1 = CGColorSpaceCreateLab(whitePoint, blackPoint, range1);
CGColorSpaceRef space2 = CGColorSpaceCreateLab(whitePoint, blackPoint, range2);
```

I create colors with the same component values and within the specified range of each space:

```
CGFloat components[] = { 50, 10, 10, 1 };
CGColorRef color1 = CGColorCreate(space1, components);
CGColorRef color2 = CGColorCreate(space2, components);
```

Do `color1` and `color2` represent the same color? Or does the `range` parameter scale the components in some way, making these two different colors? (If the latter, what value for `range` corresponds to the standard [CIELAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lab_color_space) coordinate scaling?

**Option 2: Maybe it clips the component values**

Given the two spaces defined above, say I create the following colors instead:

```
CGFloat components[] = { 50, 50, 50, 1 };
CGColorRef color1 = CGColorCreate(space1, components);
CGColorRef color2 = CGColorCreate(space2, components);
```

Now do `color1` and `color2` represent the same color? Or does the `range` parameter clip the components of `color1` to { 50, 10, 10, 1 }? (If the latter, what's the point? An extremely rough approximation of a gamut definition?  Making sure values stay within a range compatible with another data type?)

**Option 3: Maybe it's used elsewhere, like when doing gamut mapping with a perceptual rendering intent**

Having some idea of the range of L*a*b* values to expect might assist with gamut mapping, particularly in the perceptual case, but again, this seems like such a rough approximation that I don't see why it would be particularly useful.

**Option 4: Something else?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did some testing, and it looks like the answer is:

**The `range` parameter scales the a* and b* component values.**

Also, the component values do *not* appear to be clipped to the specified range.

So in the following example:

```
CGFloat range1[] = {  -10,  10,  -10,  10 };
CGFloat range2[] = { -100, 100, -100, 100 };
CGColorSpaceRef space1 = CGColorSpaceCreateLab(whitePoint, blackPoint, range1);
CGColorSpaceRef space2 = CGColorSpaceCreateLab(whitePoint, blackPoint, range2);

CGFloat components1[] = { 50, 10, 10, 1 };
CGColorRef color1 = CGColorCreate(space1, components1);

CGFloat components2[] = { 50, 100, 100, 1 };
CGColorRef color2 = CGColorCreate(space2, components2);

CGColorRef color3 = CGColorCreate(space1, components2);
```

- `color1` and `color2` represent the same color.
- `color3` appears to retain the specified component values, even though they're outside the range specified by the color space.

Finally, it looks like a range specification of { -127, 127, -127, 127 } results in a color space with the standard CIELAB scales for the a* and b* axes.

If anyone has a more authoritative answer, please post!